# Jquery Fullcalendar (arshaw's) pass selected month

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

hey i'm using the great full calendar,
i want to pass to a aspx page the selected month in the calendar
my code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
**var MONTH = m;**
//alert(new Date(y, m, 1).toString());

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: false,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function (start, end, allDay) {                       
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
    }       

        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: false,
    events: 'eventsList.aspx?d=' + MONTH // **I would like to send the MONTH HERE**
});
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I see this calendar plugin. It looks really good!

I was looking their docs and I saw this example http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar/demos/json.html

I think this is what you should do

```
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                '(should probably update your database)');
        },
```

Let me know if that helps,

Ives

Comment: it helps me for other thing but not for that one!

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing as you did and so I did it like the following...

I put a textbox(with **id="start_date"**) to my aspx page

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" size="19" name="start_date" id="start_date">
```

Then during select function, I sent the selected day, month(+1 is needed because fullCalendar start counting from 0) and year to my textbox with javascript(just above 'unselect')

```
document.getElementById('start_date').value = start.getDate() + ' - ' + (start.getMonth()+1) + ' - ' + start.getFullYear();

calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
```